# Terminal Server Overload

Tags: terminal-server

We are running Window Server 2003 Enterprise (32 bit). The server had gobs of RAM (4 gigs).

I can only get 25 users logged in and it won't allow any more to get connected.

We have a 2nd server and they can log into it.  My question is how can I increase the number of users allowed to connect to this terminal server?

We have a separate Terminal License Server setup that has 100 licenses, so that isn't an issue.

Thanks!
Bob

Comment: For clarification, are you getting an error saying no more are allowed to connect, or is performance just bad?

Comment: Your poor users... 4GB shared between 25+ users :-(

Answer (score 3):

If you are actually getting an error saying you have reached the maximum number of connections then you can set the maximum number of connections allowed in the terminal services configuration console, located in administrative tools. Go to the connections folder, then right click the RPD-TCP connection (or whatever your connection is called if you renamed it), and then go to the network adapter tab, you can change how many connections are allowed in here:

(please not this terminal server is in admin mode, but the principal is the same)
[image: RDP properties]

If however you are just having issues connecting to the server, I would suggest you look at how well the server is performing, check task managing and performance monitor to see if it is overloaded.

Answer (score 3):

4GB isn't much ram. if you figure every user needs approx 100mb, that is 2.5 GB for users, leaving 1.5 for the server. 32 bit OS has a max of 2GB for apps and 2GB for the OS.

Comment: it has been some time since i considered 4GB as 'gobs of RAM'

Answer (score 2):

There is also a GPO that will set the registry setting for TS connections.  It is located:

Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services
"Limit number of connections"

You may also think about having another Server act as a load balancer between the two terminal servers that you currently have, unless there is a specific reason that Users must be on that particular server.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at your performance logs to see what the  bottleneck is?  I would suggest turning on monitoring of disk I/O, networking, processor utilization and memory paging to start with and see if one of them is pegging.  That would then give you an indication of what you need to upgrade to increase performance.